# d3js time axis ticks duration set dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to create a bar graph with time x-axis. I am having trouble in dynamically setting ticks values.

```
.ticks(d3.time.minutes, 10)
```

above code works for me, but when data is more i want the duration to be increased to 30 minutes i.e,

```
.ticks(d3.time.minutes, 30)
```

I have tried,

```
.ticks(function () { return (dataPassed.length > 5) ? ((d3.time.minutes, 30)) : ((d3.time.minutes, 10)); })
.tickValues(xScale.domain())
```

above ways and none worked. JSfiddle link for my code:http://jsfiddle.net/hpjqt1dL/20/. I have put both datasets in the fiddle there(with less and more values). Can someone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance....

**[UPDATE:]**
Actually, its not just 2 conditions I want. My updated code is:

```
if (dataPassed.length < 4)
        {
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(xScale)
                    .orient('bottom')
                    .ticks(d3.time.minutes, 10)
                    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%H:%M'))
                    .tickSize(5);

            var boxNoBarWidth = (svgWidth + widthPad) / (dataPassed.length + 3);

        }
        else if (dataPassed.length > 3 && dataPassed.length < 6)
        {
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(xScale)
                    .orient('bottom')
                    .ticks(d3.time.minutes, 15)
                    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%H:%M'))
                    .tickSize(5);

           var boxNoBarWidth = (svgWidth + widthPad) / (dataPassed.length + 8);
        }
        else if (dataPassed.length > 5) {
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(xScale)
                    .orient('bottom')
                    .ticks(d3.time.minutes, 30)
                    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%H:%M'))
                    .tickSize(5);

           var boxNoBarWidth = (svgWidth + widthPad) / (dataPassed.length + 10);
        }
```

I also want to adjust the bar width and place ticks in centre of bar. Is there any way to achieve this with dynamically by code in time scale.

http://www.d3noob.org/2014/02/making-bar-chart-in-d3js.html, this tutorial does it but with ordinal axis.

**[UPDATE]:** Firstly, many thanks for the help. In regard to adjusting width, below are the links to screenshots of my graphs:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUy4D.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Uuk.png

Hope that gives some idea of what I mean by bar width. Let me know if it is not clear.

As *Lars* suggested I tried ordinal axis, jsfiddle of same is here: http://jsfiddle.net/hpjqt1dL/28/. If you observe there the tickvalues are exact values as in data like ..9:06, 10.45, 11.06. I want tick values to be ranged properly at regular intervals.

Comment: It sounds like you really want an ordinal scale. You also haven't said how you want to adjust the bar width.

Answer (score 0):

`.ticks()` doesn't take a function argument, but in your case you don't need it, because you're not referencing any dynamic data bound to any elements. All you need is

```
.ticks(dataPassed.length > 5 ? (d3.time.minutes, 30) : (d3.time.minutes, 10))
```

Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hpjqt1dL/23/).

Comment: Thanks Lars for reply, can you please check my updated question and help... please...